# Distinct based on one row with multiple non-aggregate columns selected

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to run a query that returns distinct AddressIDs.

The row to be retuned for each AddressID should be the one with the latest ReadDate.

I also want to return the value from (non-aggregate) columns PhoneNumber, SomeCode, and Country for the given records.

There are similar questions on here to mine, but nothing seems to suit my exact situation. I've tried different subqueries and making the other columns aggregates, but I can't seem to get the results I desire.

Say the base of the query like:

```
select cr.AddressID, cr.ReadDate, in.PhoneNumber, in.SomeCode, in.Country 
from CustomerReadings cr, in.CustomerInfo
where cr.AddressID = in.AddressID
```

For example, if I have a table that looks like:

```
AddressID     ReadDate       PhoneNumber    SomeCode    Country
1005          01/01/1997     5556565        GHS         Canada
1005          05/06/2006     5556753        ROT         USA
1005          08/12/2018     5552345        JKR         USA
2007          02/05/2012     5558746        MSC         Canada
2007          12/07/2018     5552345        RRE         France
4000          03/01/1999     5552345        RRE         France
4000          09/05/2007     5551243        MSR         USA
```

I want the query results to look like:

```
AddressID     ReadDate       PhoneNumber    SomeCode    Country
1005          08/12/2018     5552345        JKR         USA
2007          12/07/2018     5552345        RRE         France
4000          09/05/2007     5551243        MSR         USA
```

If anything is unclear please let me know and I'll update my question accordingly.

---

In the case of 1 table as you used in your answer example, the code works.

But when I bring in another table, I no longer get just one distinct AddressID back, eg:

```
select (or select distinct)
    cr.AddressID, cr.ReadDate, in.PhoneNumber, in.SomeCode, in.Country 
from
    CustomerReadings cr,
    CustomerInfo in
where
    cr.AddressID = in.AddressID
    and cr.ReadDate =
        (select max(cr2.ReadDate)
        from CustomerReadings cr2
        where cr2.AddressID = cr.AddressID)
order by
    2 desc,
    1;
```

Comment: Have you done some research???  There must be tons of example if you search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be questions that are very similar.  I use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.readdate = (select max(t2.readdate) from t t2 where t2.addressid = t.addressid);
```

Comment: Hey, could you take a look at the update I made on my question? I'm having an issue. Tks

Comment: @ScopeY . . . This question is clearly about one table, so it is more appropriate to ask this in a second question.  Joining in another table should not change your getting the latest date.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where readdate = (select max(t1.readdate) from table t1 where t1.addressid = t.addressid);
```

If you are working with latest version of `MySQL`, then `row_number()` would helpful :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by addressid order by readdate desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

However, if the readdate has ties, then `row_number()` would no longer help use `dense_rank()` instead.